# Dynamic SQL via jOOQ for paginating joined tables with same-named columns

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq, dynamicquery

I'm following a [jOOQ blog post about paging metadata](https://blog.jooq.org/calculating-pagination-metadata-without-extra-roundtrips-in-sql/), and trying to implement it generally for a project. It demonstrates how to generically take an existing `Select<?>` and wrap it up to contain information about the current page, and how many other pages exist:

> ```java
> public static Select<?> paginate(
>     DSLContext ctx,
>     Select<?> original,
>     Field<?>[] sort,
>     int limit,
>     int offset ) {
>     Table<?> u = original.asTable("u");
>     Field<Integer> totalRows = count().over().as("total_rows");
>     Field<Integer> row = rowNumber().over().orderBy(u.fields(sort))
>         .as("row");
>  
>     Table<?> t = ctx
>         .select(u.asterisk())
>         .select(totalRows, row)
>         .from(u)
>         .orderBy(u.fields(sort))
>         .limit(limit)
>         .offset(offset)
>         .asTable("t");
>  
>     Select<?> result = ctx
>         .select(t.fields(original.getSelect().toArray(Field[]::new)))
>         .select(
>             count().over().as("actual_page_size"),
>             field(max(t.field(row)).over().eq(t.field(totalRows)))
>                 .as("last_page"),
>             t.field(totalRows),
>             t.field(row),
>             t.field(row).minus(inline(1)).div(limit).plus(inline(1))
>                 .as("current_page"))
>         .from(t)
>         .orderBy(t.fields(sort));
>  
>     // System.out.println(result);
>     return result;
> }
> ```
>
> And here’s how you call the utility:
>
> ```
> java System.out.println(
>     paginate(
>         ctx,
>         ctx.select(ACTOR.ACTOR_ID, ACTOR.FIRST_NAME, ACTOR.LAST_NAME)
>            .from(ACTOR),
>         new Field[] { ACTOR.ACTOR_ID },
>         15,
>         30
>     ).fetch() );
> ```
>
> Notice that you can plug in arbitrary SQL fragments into that utility and paginate them. Irrespective of the complexity (including joins, other window functions, grouping, recursion, and what not), jOOQ will have you covered and will now paginate things for you.

This works nicely for simple cases, but I am finding that it fails in any case where two columns happen to have the same name across joins - normally, the `record.into(FooRecord.class)` and `record.into(BarRecord.class)` would extract those columns and make them separately available to the caller.

For example, given two tables, `foo` and `bar`, where both have an `id` column, and `bar` has a `foo_id` foreign key. Then, I can write:

```java
var select = ctx
   .select(FOO.fields())
   .select(BAR.fields())
   .from(BAR)
   .leftJoin(FOO).on(BAR.FOO_ID.eq(FOO.ID));

// Render the SQL
System.out.println(select);
var data = select.fetch();

// Show the full query's results, then the fields that came from FOO and BAR
System.out.println(data);
System.out.println(data.get(2).into(FOO));
System.out.println(data.get(2).into(BAR));
```

Results:

```
select "myschema"."foo"."id", "myschema"."bar"."id", "myschema"."bar"."foo_id"
from "myschema"."bar"
  left outer join "myschema"."foo"
    on "myschema"."bar"."foo_id" = "myschema"."foo"."id"
+----+----+------+
|  id|  id|foo_id|
+----+----+------+
|   1|   1|     1|
|   2|   2|     2|
|   2|   3|     2|
+----+----+------+

+----+
|  id|
+----+
|   2|
+----+

+----+------+
|  id|foo_id|
+----+------+
|   3|     2|
+----+------+
```

Both jOOQ and the database (Postgres in this case) are happy with this, despite having more than one column with the same name.

Next, I try to pass this `Select<?>` to the paginate() method above:

```
var pagedSelect = paginate(ctx, original, new Field[] { FOO.ID }, 10, 0);

System.out.println(pagedSelect);
var pagedData = pagedSelect.fetch();//error
```

```
select
  "t"."id",
  "t"."id",
  "t"."foo_id",
  count(*) over () as "actual_page_size",
  (max("t"."row") over () = "t"."total_rows") as "last_page",
  "t"."total_rows",
  "t"."row",
  ((("t"."row" - 1) / 10) + 1) as "current_page"
from (
  select
    "u".*,
    count(*) over () as "total_rows",
    row_number() over (order by "u"."id") as "row"
  from (
    select "myschema"."foo"."id", "myschema"."bar"."id", "myschema"."bar"."foo_id"
    from "myschema"."bar"
      left outer join "myschema"."foo"
        on "myschema"."bar"."foo_id" = "myschema"."foo"."id"
  ) as "u"
  order by "u"."id"
  offset 0 rows
  fetch next 10 rows only
) as "t"
order by "t"."id"
```

```
ERROR: column referenced "id" is ambiguous
```

My naive approach was to first try to modify `paginate(...)` to make the outer-most `SELECT` reference the fully qualified fields, table and all, but since we're querying from an anonymous table, that doesn't work, same error (though for a different reason, since now jOOQ is generating an alias for `original`.

Next I considered trying to visit `original` and create a copy of it, using `AS` to rename columns as f1, f2, f3, but I couldn't find a straightforward way to do this rewrite. Even if this had worked, it would make it hard to map them back again from the caller, which would need to then know the order of all the .select()ed fields to be able to find them again - and since the `original` might have itself been built from other dynamic SQL operations, that might not be feasible.

Finally I considered an approach where every column of every table was already qualified with the table name already, but beyond this being onerous, it also doesn't help at all in cases where a table could be joined twice into the same query.

What's the correct dynamic SQL approach with jOOQ to make it possible to wrap a query with pagination, and still map records back to their individual tables?

--

*EDIT: Based on the comments, I've modified the query from the blog post, and while this actually emits runnable SQL, the premise of the blog post still seems faulty, and still eludes me.*

> Irrespective of the complexity (including joins, other window functions, grouping, recursion, and what not), jOOQ will have you covered and will now paginate things for you.

In this iteration, the `as` syntax for the nested selects now come with renamed columns, and the outer query uses those column names. In an attempt to still permit `Record.into(Table)` to work, it maps back again to the original columns, in order:

```java
  public static Select<?> paginate(
          DSLContext ctx,
          Select<?> original,
          Field<?>[] sort,
          int limit,
          int offset ) {
    Map<List<String>, String> aliases = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    List<Field<?>> reverseAlias = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Field<?>> select = original.getSelect();
    for (int i = 0; i < select.size(); i++) {
      Field<?> field = select.get(i);
      aliases.put(Arrays.asList(field.getQualifiedName().getName()), "c" + i);
    }

    Table<?> u = original.asTable("u", aliases.values().toArray(String[]::new));
    Field<Integer> totalRows = count().over().as("total_rows");
    String[] sortFieldNames = Arrays.stream(sort).map(o -> aliases.get(Arrays.asList(o.getQualifiedName().getName()))).toArray(String[]::new);
    Field<Integer> row = rowNumber().over().orderBy(u.fields(sortFieldNames))
            .as("row");

    Table<?> t = ctx.select(u.asterisk())
            .select(totalRows, row)
            .from(u)
            .orderBy(u.fields(sortFieldNames))
            .limit(limit)
            .offset(offset)
            .asTable("t");

    for (int i = 0; i < select.size(); i++) {
      Field<?> field = select.get(i);
      reverseAlias.add(t.field("c" + i).as(field.getName()));
    }

    Select<?> result = ctx
            .select(reverseAlias)
            .select(
                    count().over().as("actual_page_size"),
                    field(max(t.field(row)).over().eq(t.field(totalRows)))
                            .as("last_page"),
                    t.field(totalRows),
                    t.field(row),
                    t.field(row).minus(inline(1)).div(limit).plus(inline(1))
                            .as("current_page"))
            .from(t)
            .orderBy(t.fields(sortFieldNames));

    return result;
  }
```

This generates the following SQL:

```sql
select
  "t"."c1" as "id",
  "t"."c2" as "id",
  "t"."c3" as "foo_id",
  count(*) over () as "actual_page_size",
  (max("t"."row") over () = "t"."total_rows") as "last_page",
  "t"."total_rows",
  "t"."row",
  ((("t"."row" - 1) / 10) + 1) as "current_page"
from (
  select
    "u".*,
    count(*) over () as "total_rows",
    row_number() over (order by "u"."c1") as "row"
  from (
    select "myschema"."foo"."id", "myschema"."bar"."id", "myschema"."bar"."foo_id"
    from "myschema"."bar"
      left outer join "myschema"."foo"
        on "myschema"."bar"."foo_id" = "myschema"."foo"."id"
  ) as "u" ("c1", "c2", "c3")
  order by "u"."c1"
  offset 0 rows
  fetch next 10 rows only
) as "t"
order by "t"."c1"
```

Note that as in the initial result sets, the first two columns are still labeled as `id`. However, `Record.into(Table)` no longer has the context it needs to understand that the first `id` column is for the `foo` table, and the second is for the `bar` table:

```
+----+----+------+----------------+---------+----------+----+------------+
|  id|  id|foo_id|actual_page_size|last_page|total_rows| row|current_page|
+----+----+------+----------------+---------+----------+----+------------+
|   1|   1|     1|               3|true     |         3|   1|           1|
|   2|   2|     2|               3|true     |         3|   2|           1|
|   2|   3|     2|               3|true     |         3|   3|           1|
+----+----+------+----------------+---------+----------+----+------------+

+----+
|  id|
+----+
|   2|
+----+

+----+------+
|  id|foo_id|
+----+------+
|   2|     2|
+----+------+
```

So, to put the question in concrete terms: Is there a way to indicate to jOOQ that a `Select<?>`'s fields should be mapped to a particular Table?

And, as a more general question, but less subject to the X/Y problem: How can this paginate() method actually be used as in the example, with joins, where the joined tables have colliding column names? Is there a problem with this strategy of building up a query dynamically, and is there another strategy that can be followed instead, without this shortcoming?

Comment: You just have to rename all the columns of the original query to `c1`, `c2`, ..., `cn` in the derived table, and then rename them back to the original name in the outer most query.

Comment: @LukasEder that makes sense from a general SQL perspective (though the final order-by does need to continue to use the `c1` name, rather than the original `id` name), but how does one dynamically do this using jOOQ's API? That is, is it possible to write a method like `paginate()` that takes a `Select<?>` in this way, without mandating that the caller preprocess that select? Or is it possible for `paginate()` implementation to copy+modify the `original` Select to add those `as` expressions?

Comment: It's certainly doable. Do you have a *specific* question that you're blocked with? Your question seems very open ended, and hard to answer as it is...

Comment: I was trying to use the paginate() example as a specific case of dynamic sql + jooq's Record.into(), as a way to understand how to best layer/separate these concerns. I have a partial answer based on your thoughts so far, but it doesn't correctly map fields so that Record behaves as expected yet. I'll answer or update the question shortly based on what I work out.

Comment: Short of forcing my paginate(..) callers be aware of the implementation details of the helper method, I wasn't able to find a way to make `Record.into(Table)` generally work. I've added a small update to the question, and tried to rephrase both in concrete ("how do I do X with Y") and more general ("here's what i'm trying to achieve") terms. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: In the spirit of Stack Overflow, rather than having a 5 page question with frequently amended details at the end, better ask a new, *very specific* question that can be answered very briefly. That way, both you and future visitors of this question will get more value out of the interaction. As far as I'm concerned, I don't want to keep track of your step by step progress in such a complex topic. It would be too time consuming. Think about it this way: I would have to re-read the entire question again now. This is why I asked for a *specific* question.

Comment: Of course - I had felt it was already specific enough, but this might mostly highlight how long it has been since I've worked with jOOQ and SQL... Thank you again for taking a look.

Comment: In terms of specificity, there are a ton of edge cases to consider, which would take forever to get right in an answer. I just don't think the question really fits the Stack Overflow Q&A format. Maybe this is more of a feature request? Though even there, it's hard to specify what particular set of edge cases should be addressed...

Comment: This might in and of itself be the answer, that dynamic SQL of this type isn't really capable of (or intended for) what I'm asking, without some other concessions, and my lack of familiarity here is blinding me to the downsides of what I thought I had put together.

Comment: I don't think so. jOOQ's internals do these things all the time, e.g. to emulate `LIMIT` using window functions. It's just a bit more complex than a simple Q&A if all the edge cases need to be considered.